# prototype field is empty after form(form) but set when set before the form(form) symfony

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, doctrine-orm, twig

when I follow this tutorial: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html
and I render the

```
<ul class="tags" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.tags.vars.prototype)|e }}">
...
</ul>
```

the prototype stay empty if I put it after the {{ form(form)}} but gets filled If I put it i before the {{ form(form) }} tag. any one an idea why this is and how to solve it.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag {{ form(form) }} is supposed to output all your form, so there is nothing to output  after this tag. 
If the tag {{ form(form) }} does not output the prototype, then it was not configured right in the form type class.

But if you chose to output prototype by using form_widget, you should not use form(form) and should output the form [by parts](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-each-field-by-hand):

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}

    <div>
        {{ form_row(form.another_form_property) }}
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul class="tags" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.tags.vars.prototype)|e }}">
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```